# how to push longitude and latitude to server for every certain distances covered

Tags: android, location

how to push longitude and latitude to server for every certain distances covered
the requirement here to solve to push data to server accoring to 1000m every time

public class LocationUpdateIntentService extends IntentService implements LocationListener {

```
private static final Location TODO = null;
private Activity activity;
//Location Manager
LocationManager locationManager;
public static Boolean isRunning = false;
Location location;
Map<String, String> inputMap;
float minimumDistanceBetweenUpdates = 10;
double initialLat;
double initialLong;
double finalLat;
double finalLong;
LocationRequest locationRequest;

public LocationUpdateIntentService() {
    super("locationUpdateService");
}

public LocationUpdateIntentService(Activity activity) {
    super("locationUpdateService");
    this.activity = activity;
}

public LocationUpdateIntentService(Activity baseActivity, Map<String, String> inputMap) {
    super("locationUpdateService");
    this.activity = baseActivity;
    this.inputMap = inputMap;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    /*if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
        if (Permissions.getLocationPermissionStatus(activity)){
            location = getLastKnownLocation();
        }
    } else {
        location = getLastKnownLocation();
    }*/
    location = getLastKnownLocation();

    LocationRequest request = new LocationRequest();
    request.setSmallestDisplacement(minimumDistanceBetweenUpdates);
}

Handler mHandler = new Handler();
Runnable mHandlerTask = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (!isRunning) {
            startListening();
        }
        mHandler.postDelayed(mHandlerTask, C.TIME_LOCATION_UPDATE);
    }
};

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    mHandlerTask.run();
}

public void startListening() {
    if (location != null) {
        location = getLastKnownLocation();

        initialLong = location.getLongitude();
        initialLat = location.getLatitude();
       /* String latitudeintial = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
        String longitudeintial = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());

        // server Call : Location Update Server Call
        LocationUpdateServerCall locationUpdateServerCall = new LocationUpdateServerCall(getApplicationContext());
        locationUpdateServerCall.pushLocationUpdateServerCall(latitudeintial, longitudeintial);*/

    }
}

public Location getLastKnownLocation() {
    Location location = null;
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    List<String> providers = locationManager.getProviders(true);

    for (String provider : providers) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return TODO;
        }
        Location l = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        if (l == null) {
            continue;
        }
        if (location == null
                || l.getAccuracy() < location.getAccuracy()) {
            location = l;
        }
    }
    if (location == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return location;
}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    this.location = location;
    if (location != null) {
       /* String latitude = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
        String longitude = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());

        // server Call : Location Update Server Call
        LocationUpdateServerCall locationUpdateServerCall = new LocationUpdateServerCall(getApplicationContext());
        locationUpdateServerCall.pushLocationUpdateServerCall(latitude, longitude);*/

        finalLat = location.getLatitude();
        finalLong = location.getLongitude();
        double distance = CalculationByDistance(initialLat, initialLong, finalLat, finalLong);
        if(distance == 500){
            LocationUpdateServerCall locationUpdateServerCall = new LocationUpdateServerCall(getApplicationContext());
            locationUpdateServerCall.pushLocationUpdateServerCall(String.valueOf(finalLat), String.valueOf(finalLat));
        }

    }
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

}

public double CalculationByDistance(double initialLat, double initialLong, double finalLat, double finalLong) {
/*PRE: All the input values are in radians!*/

    double latDiff = finalLat - initialLat;
    double longDiff = finalLong - initialLong;
    double earthRadius = 6371; //In Km if you want the distance in km

    double distance = 2 * earthRadius * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Math.sin(latDiff / 2.0), 2) + Math.cos(initialLat) * Math.cos(finalLat) * Math.pow(Math.sin(longDiff / 2), 2)));

    return distance;

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

there are distanceTo method to find distance between loction.below is example of getting distnce between to location over km; after getting specified distance put a req to send position to server;

```
**location.distanceTo(location) / km)**
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use method `requestLocationUpdates` with `LocationManager`. It will reduce your work. Here is the code.

```
//it will call every 1000 milisec and on more than 10m distance

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 10, new android.location.LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    //Your API calls here
                }

                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

                }
    });
```